# Does Minato still have Yin-Kurama?

Tags: naruto

I thought Minato kept Yin-Kurama because I heard that Minato gave Naruto most of his nine tails chakra, but not all of it.

I wonder if Minato still has some of the Yin-half Kurama. If not please explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe he does.

During the final battle, Madara largely succeeded in his goal of extracting Kurama out of Naruto.  This meant that Naruto was going to *die* if something weren't done.

Enter Minato and Yin Kurama.  A transfer of Yin Kurama was made into Naruto *from* Minato so that he would survive having Yang Kurama extracted from him.

It isn't the case that Minato contains Kurama any longer.